# Saving null as id, with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, null

I'm in a strange position where I need to save `@Id` of an `@Entity` as `null`

The whole project is build using hibernate and entities. But for this one legacy entity, there is a trigger in the table itself to generate ID.

As a result, trying to insert anything but null will result in an error.

When trying to `.save()` an entity with null id, hibernate will throw

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()
```

EDIT:

Clarification, i need to do `.save()` where ID column is null because:

Trigger in the table will (before any insert) check if ID is null, then do SELECT to get the last ID and increment that by 1 and finally insert this new row to table. The trigger will error in case ID is anything but null.

Comment: A trigger or a sequence or an identity?

Comment: not sure if i understand. Table has trigger which will SELECT last id, then do id+1 and insert that. i've tried different GenerationType strategies, but none seem to work. there is no sequencer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just mark the id as autogenerated by the underlying database:

```
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Long id;
```

`GenerationType.IDENTITY` is generally designed for when the PK is set as `auto increment` but, from the JPA point of view, it is just moving the duty of generating the id to the database engine. And thats happening in your case by the usage of a trigger.