# Save entity JPA with null id

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to create a function for registering a user.

```
@Service
public class RegistrationService {
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(RegistrationService.class);
    
    public Boolean createNewUser(Registration registration) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUserName(registration.getUserName());
        user.setPassword(registration.getPassword());
        logger.info("attempting to create user: {}", user);
        
        try {
            userRepository.save(user);          
        } catch(Exception e) {
            logger.error("Failed to register user: {}", e.getStackTrace());
            return false;
        }
        
        Account account = new Account();
        account.setUserId(user.getId());
        account.setBillingAddress(registration.getBillingAddress());
        account.setBillingCountry(registration.getBillingCountry());
        account.setBillingProvince(registration.getBillingProvince());
        account.setPhoneNumber(registration.getPhoneNumber());
        account.setZip(registration.getZip());
        logger.info("attempting to create account: {}", account);
        
        try {
            account = accountRepository.save(account);          
        } catch(Exception e) {
            logger.error("Failed to register account: {}", e.getStackTrace());
            return false;
        }
        
        
        return true;
    }
}
```

I followed the advice from this post: [Saving null as id, with hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507484/saving-null-as-id-with-hibernate), but the solution did not work for me.
Here is my user class

```
package com.company.app.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Table(name="user")
@Data
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    private String userName;

    private String password;

    
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    
    public String getUserName() {
        return this.userName;
    }
    
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }
}
```

Here is my account class

```
package com.company.app.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Table(name="account")
@Data
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    private Long userId;

    private String billingAddress;
    
    private String billingProvince;
    
    private String billingCountry;

    private String phoneNumber;

    private String zip;
    
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    
    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public String getBillingAddress() {
        return billingAddress;
    }

    public void setBillingAddress(String billingAddress) {
        this.billingAddress = billingAddress;
    }

    public String getBillingProvince() {
        return billingProvince;
    }

    public void setBillingProvince(String billingProvince) {
        this.billingProvince = billingProvince;
    }

    public String getBillingCountry() {
        return billingCountry;
    }

    public void setBillingCountry(String billingCountry) {
        this.billingCountry = billingCountry;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getZip() {
        return zip;
    }

    public void setZip(String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }
}
```

My log shows the following output

```
2021-04-14 14:40:09.265  INFO 15092 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.c.app.service.RegistrationService      : attempting to create user: User(id=null, userName=evan, password=test123)
2021-04-14 14:40:09.266 ERROR 15092 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.c.app.service.RegistrationService      : Failed to register user: com.company.app.service.RegistrationService.createNewUser(RegistrationService.java:26)
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Here is the stack trace
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown return value type: org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:124) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_172]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_172]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_172]

Comment: Have you read the stacktrace? It is complaining about your controller method **not** about storing the entity. At least judging from that stacktrace, which I doubt is the stacktrace you get from your user service. Don't do `e.getStacktrace` just do `e` in your logging, try again and post the actual stacktrace as that will tell you **exactly** what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you get this error because you didn't set id.

Try add user.setId(registration.getId());

Comment: I think the id value you set in the account is not defined above.so it sounds null

Comment: I don't want to set the id.

Answer (score 0):

At the End, the ID needs a value.
In your case the ID is annotated with @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
This means that you don't have to set the value for the ID in your Program.
But a value is still needed, therefore the DB has to take care of setting the ID.
In a mysql-table for example you can achieve this by defining the ID-Column as

```
`ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```