# Custom sql statement using Spring JPA

Tags: spring, jpa

I am trying to insert a record into a table called user. The method that I am trying to troubleshoot is  `insertNewUser` which is located in my class `UserRepositoryCustom`. I am using `JPARepository` and `EntityManger` to accomplish this. The I am still unable to insert a user into the table. Any help with this would be very much appreciated.

UserRepositoryImpl

```
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepositoryCustom {
    
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    
    public void insertNewUser(User user) {
        entityManager.createNativeQuery("INSERT INTO user (username,password) VALUES (?,?)")
        .setParameter(1,user.getUserName())
        .setParameter(2,user.getPassword());
    }
}
```

UserRepositoryCustom

```
public interface UserRepositoryCustom {
    public void insertNewUser(User user);
}
```

UserRepository

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>, UserRepositoryCustom {
    User findById(int id);
    User findByUserName(String userName);
        
}
```

Comment: Why are you writing your own query and not just use the provided `save` method? Also the `@Repository` on the interface is useless and without a transaction nothing will be inserted. But as mentioned in the beginning why write your own insert instead of using JPA for it?

Comment: I was having issues trying to insert a User record into the database the record looks like User(id=null,name="evan",password="test123")

Comment: But still why not just use `save`? That should do all you need. If there is an issue, it is probably related to your mapping in your `User` entity. Working around that with custom SQL isn't the proper solution.

Comment: Thank you I opened a question here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67097380/save-entity-jpa-with-null-id/67104535#67104535, but none of the solutions worked. So, I tried something else.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was not using `@Autowired` on my service class's contructor to inject the repository beans. When I invoked the Repository bean methods nothing was happening. Essentially the Repository beans were just null objects.